# passing derived class object to base class reference parameter

Tags: java

I have a base class `User` and 2 derived class `Admin` and `Manager` as below.
Note: this is just a pseudo code

`Base class - User`

```
public class User {

    public String userId;
    public String name;
    public String type;
}
```

`Derived class - Admin`

```
public class Admin extends User {

    public String prop1;
    public String prop2;
}
```

`Derived class - Manager`

```
public class Manager extends User {

    public String prop3;
    public String prop4;
}
```

The base class contains common properties which are shared across Admin and Manager.

Now, I have a method which calls an API to create a user. The same API call is used to create different kind of user(Admin/Manager)

```
public class Response<T>{
     public int statusCode;
     public T result;
}


public class UserCreation{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     RequestHandler requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
     User userRequest = requestHandler.createUserCreationRequest("Admin");
     UserCreationDao.createUser(userRequest);

     User userRequest = requestHandler.createUserCreationRequest("Manager");
     UserCreationDao.createUser(userRequest);
  }
        
}

public class RequestHandler{
    public User createUserCreationRequest(String userType) {
        switch (userType) {
            case "Admin":
                return createAdminRequest();
            case "Manager":
                return createManagerRequest();
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid processor");
        }
    }

    private Admin createAdminRequest(){
        Admin admin = new Admin();
        admin.setName("Admin");
        admin.setType("Admin");
        admin.setProp1("prop1");
        admin.serProp2("prop2");
        return Admin;
    }

    private Manager createManagerRequest(){
        Manager manager = new Manager();
        manager.setName("Manager");
        manager.setType("Manager");
        manager.setProp3("prop2");
        manager.serProp4("prop3");
        return manager;
    }
}

public class UserCreationDao{
    public void createUser(User userRequest) {

        Response<User> response = userapi.createuser(HttpMethod.POST, "/users", userRequest, new ParameterizedTypeReference<Response<User>>() {
        }, key);

    }
}
```

Currently when the code hits the createUser method in the UserCreationDao, the Response object which contains a property `result` must be populated with the derived class object details - Admin or Manager. However, in the current code, since I am passing the type as User to the Response obejct, it does not return all the properties of Admin and manager class.

I am looking for ways where I can still use just one method but pass different derived class reference to the Response object so that the `result` property on the response object is populated based on the derived class.

Comment: You've placed two different language tags, for some reason.  Which language are you actually using?  Please delete whichever tag is wrong.

Comment: The fact that you code includes `extends`, I can only conclude that it's Java and not C#. The fact that your methods start with lower-case letters supports that, although that's not conclusive. the fact that the languages look very similar doesn't mean that what applies to one automatically applies to the other. If your question is not about C#, please don't tag it C#. You're wasting people's time by tricking them into opening irrelevant questions.

Comment: Ok, I have removed the C# tag. This question is Java related

Comment: Which library are you using to trigger the request? The "issue" will probably be the library   which does the serialization/deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on which libraries are used for serialization/deserialization. If Jackson is used you could change the Response class in the following way:

```
public class Response<T> {
    private int statusCode;
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "className")
    private T result;
}
```

you will need to enable typing in the serialization. Here is an example code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        om.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);

        User user = Admin.builder()
                .name("admin")
                .type("ADMIN")
                .userId("1")
                .prop1("ADMIN_PROP1")
                .prop2("ADMIN_PROP2")
                .build();

        Response<User> resp = Response.<User>builder()
                .statusCode(200)
                .result(user)
                .build();

        String json = om.writeValueAsString(resp);
        System.out.println("JSON: " + json);

        JavaType type = om.getTypeFactory()
                .constructParametricType(Response.class, User.class);
        Response<User> response = om.readValue(json, type);
        System.out.println("OBJ: " + response.toString());
    }
```

Which in turn will produce the following output:

```
JSON: {"statusCode":200,"result":{"className":"test.Admin","userId":"1","name":"admin","type":"ADMIN","prop1":"ADMIN_PROP1","prop2":"ADMIN_PROP2"}}
OBJ: Response(statusCode=200, result=Admin(super=User(userId=1, name=admin, type=ADMIN), prop1=ADMIN_PROP1, prop2=ADMIN_PROP2))
```

As you can see jackson adds the className attribute to the JSON which it later uses to deserialize to the correct User sub class. (in this case back to Admin)